# How to use GDAL-commands in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal

I recently used a GDAL-command working with the OSGeo4W command line, but it does not feel that comfortable. Is there a way to somehow execute a GDAL-command directly in QGIS?

Right now the gdal-extension is installed in QGIS, but i can not find a command line.

Comment: Have you considered writing python scripts which pass GDAL commands? Very easy to document and edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the gdal extensions in QGIS you should be seeing the commandline output at the bottom of each prompt.  You can copy / paste that into a terminal if you want.

If you want a python console, like you might see in arcMap 10+, a plugin exists.  Here is a link to [a tutorial](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/python_in_qgis_tutorial2.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It worked using copy&paste+ the terminal. Additionally i realized that it is also possible to manipulate the commandline output at the bottom of the prompt and add extra command options.